# How to preallocate memory for a std::map or QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, stl

I am developing a program, where performance is critical. There I use a `QMultiMap`, which is a class provided by the Qt framework, similar to `std::map`.

```
QMultiMap<int, SomeClass> heavilyUsedMap;

void prepareMap()
{
    ...
    heavilyUsedMap.reserve(nEntries); // There is no reserve.
    // fill heavilyUsedMap with a known number of entries.
}

void useMap()
{
    // computations
    heavilyUsedMap.clear();
}
```

I use `prepareMap()` a lot. When I want to optimize, it would make sense to allocate the memory for `heavilyUsedMap` .

Indeed the containers: `QVector<T>`, `QHash<Key, T>`, `QSet<T>`, `QString`, and `QByteArray` all provide this possibility, but `QMap<Key, T>` and `QMultiMap<Key, T>` don't.

Why is this so and how can I preallocate memory for the `QMap<Key, T>` and `QMultiMap<Key, T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely backed by a binary search tree, so preallocation isn't common as it is usually a linked structure with each node dynamically allocated as required.

If order is not important consider using a hash map instead, you can preallocate and it is also more performant generally.  So `QHashMap<int, SomeClass>`.

I also see your key type is int, if the domain is sufficiently small you can use a perfect hash which is essentially an array.  So `QVector<SomeClass>`, which will be even more performant than a hash map.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand this correctly, there are no "reallocations when out of preallocated memory" like in a std::vector

Comment: Correct.  Like a linked list, each node stays at the same memory location for its lifetime.

Comment: It's actually implemented using skipped lists (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmap.html#details) and not a binary search tree, though the preallocation argument also holds for such structure.

Answer (score 5):

The map is a *node-based* container, so each element is allocated separately. There is no such thing as "preallocation", and it would have no advantage (i.e. the total time spent would be the same).